# Possible combinations for this table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am writing an application which needs to decide base on the below table. The values of XYZ must be satisfied with an AND statement, which will trigger an event in the code.

```
        C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     C6     C7     C8
 X =    *1*    *1*    *1*     0     *1*     0      0      0 &&
 Y =     0     *1*    *1*    *1*     0      0     *1*     0 &&
 Z =     0      0     *1*    *1*    *1*    *1*     0      0 &&
```

I will be storing the values for every 10min run which will iterate. Once any of these values reach my threshold level which is also the number of iterations, the application will do it's thing.

Final Check = C1 + C5 + C2

```
 1st run = C1     2nd run = C5     3rd run = C2     checkpoint
 X = 1            X = 1            X = 1            X = 3
 Y = 0            Y = 0            Y = 1            Y = 1
 Z = 0            Z = 1            Z = 0            Z = 0
```

I need a formula to derive the combinations. Assuming there are 3 iterations involved, 1st run, 2nd run, 3rd run. How do I formulate a possible number of combinations base on the above that will trigger my payload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> "the application will do it's thing [...] trigger my payload"

[Should I be worried?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/)

The description is not very clear. I interpret the question as: find  the number of ways to accumulate
the values $3,1,1$ for $X,Y,Z$ after $3$ iterations. (C1+C2+C5 is $3,1,1$, not $3,1,0$ as stated in the table). 
If so, the answer is easy:

- $1$ possibility for $X$, namely $111$
- $3$ possibilities for $Y$, namely $100, 010, 001$
- $3$ possibilities for $Z$, for the same reason.

Hence, the answer is $1\cdot 3\cdot 3=9$ combinations.